# can't write to /

Tags: hard-drive, ext4

I have to do this almost every day. Do you think it caused by a hardware (HDD) error or by my system (kubuntu 18.04). Can Discover corrupt file system?

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 133161 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 133162 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133163 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133165 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133175 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133182 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133183 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133186 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133187 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133188 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133189 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133190 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133191 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133192 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133195 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133196 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133197 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133198 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133200 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133201 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133202 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133203 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133224 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 133251 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 135285 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 135761 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 135942 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 145211 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 471569 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 471570 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 471571 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 471572 seems to contain garbage.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 471573 seems to contain garbage.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 471574 seems to contain garbage.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 471575 seems to contain garbage.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 471576 seems to contain garbage.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 471577 seems to contain garbage.  Clear ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes to all
Inode 471578 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? yes

Inode 471579 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 471580 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? yes

Deleted inode 471581 has zero dtime.  Fix? yes

Inode 471582 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? yes

Inode 471583 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? yes

Inode 471584 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? yes

Inode 524293 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'ssif.h' in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/ipmi (471560) has deleted/unused inode 471570.  Clear? yes

Entry 'si.h' in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/ipmi (471560) has deleted/unused inode 471569.  Clear? yes

Entry 'watchdog.h' in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/ipmi (471560) has deleted/unused inode 471571.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471585> (471585) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471587> (471587) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471589> (471589) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471591> (471591) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471593> (471593) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471595> (471595) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry '..' in <471574>/<471598> (471598) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Entry 'ippp' in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config (164390) has deleted/unused inode 471572.  Clear? yes

Entry 'ipv6' in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config (164390) has deleted/unused inode 471574.  Clear? yes

Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Unconnected directory inode 471585 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471587 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471589 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471591 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471593 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471595 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Unconnected directory inode 471598 (...)
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Inode 133266 ref count is 1, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 145410 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Inode 164390 ref count is 905, should be 903.  Fix? yes

Inode 471585 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471587 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471589 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471591 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471593 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471595 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 471598 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Unattached zero-length inode 471600.  Clear? yes

Unattached zero-length inode 471601.  Clear? yes

Unattached zero-length inode 471602.  Clear? yes

Unattached zero-length inode 471603.  Clear? yes

Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(635346--635354) -(636151--636157) -(636180--636189) -(636611--636615) -(1093705--1093707) -(1397248--1397688) -(1702912--1703066) -(1703424--1703709) -(1708032--1712127) -(1714176--1716223) -(1720320--1724244) -(1724288--1724339) -(1724736--1724769) -(1724800--1724926) -(1725440--1725656) -(1725696--1725753) -(1725824--1725885) -(1725952--1726102) -(1726144--1726190) -(1726208--1726337) -(1726400--1726438) -(1726464--1726548) -(1728512--1756317) -(1757184--1761352) -(1761408--1761510) -(2679296--2680042) -(2681856--2682367) -(2682880--2683114) -(2820096--2822143) -(2854912--2856959) -(2865152--2873343) -(2918400--2919937) -(7902750--7902754)
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #19 (10210, counted=10241).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #33 (25660, counted=25663).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #42 (12096, counted=12537).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #51 (7200, counted=7641).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #52 (5347, counted=24610).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #53 (7975, counted=31861).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #81 (7351, counted=8845).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #86 (3339, counted=5387).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #87 (9328, counted=19568).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #89 (26471, counted=28009).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #241 (20173, counted=20178).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong (6607648, counted=6665979).
Fix? yes

Inode bitmap differences:  -(133161--133163) -133165 -133175 -(133182--133183) -(133186--133192) -(133195--133198) -(133200--133203) -133224 -133251 -135285 -135761 -135942 -145211 -(471569--471584) -524293
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #16 (3370, counted=3397).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #17 (4960, counted=4961).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #57 (5, counted=21).
Fix? yes

Directories count wrong for group #57 (2526, counted=2521).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #64 (4934, counted=4935).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong (2217552, counted=2217823).
Fix? yes


/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda2: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM *****
/dev/sda2: 346273/2564096 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 3574021/10240000 blocks
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you try to write on / with root privileges? And yes, this is not the best practice, would you mind me asking what's the use case of this?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1093653

Comment: @user68186 , looks like I did not explain it clear. Basically what happens is that every one in a while my system behaves like if the HDD was 100% full. I can't update the system, I can't install anything, if I open any program, e.g. Dolphin errors popping up, e.g. can't write to bla-bla-bla/dolphinrc. The only way to solve this is: 1. reboot 2.system would boot in busybox itself. 3.try exit busybox but it tells you do 'fsck' 4. do fsck and fix errors 5. after that the system boots normally again and works well until it happens again in a couple of days

Comment: @skoch13 please my comment above. Hopefully it explains what is happening

Comment: @mth1417un the guide seems to be about Wubi which I don't use. Actually I am not sure if Wubi is alive nowadays. 'fsck' does help but I am trying to figure out why do I need to do it almost every day. Is there an issue in my kubuntu install? Or is my HDD going to kick the bucket soon? I guess the only way to check is to try to move the system on another HDD and try again...

Comment: Please put all the explanations in the question above. This may help others understand the problem better. Not everyone reads comments.